# Using Reflection to set Properties in an Unit Test

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

Here is my scenario:

I created an abstract class to reduce code duplication, and enforce some methods to be implemented by concrete classes that extend this class.

```
abstract class BaseClass
{
    protected $arrayField;
   
    ...

    public function getModifiedArrayField($constraints)
    {
        // do things to $arrayField and return a modified
        // version of the arrayField. Depends only on the
        // $constraints and some `array_*` functions
        return $modifiedArray;
    }

    // ... some other methods for reducing code duplication

    // ... abstract methods that needs to be implemented

}
```

I thought it would be a good idea to test the concrete methods in the abstract class itself.

The `$arrayField` will be populated by an abstract method in an concrete class.

Since I wanted to test the functionality of the method that modifies that property (but does not mutate), I wrote an unit test as the following.

```
class BaseClassTest extents PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase

    private $sut;

    public function setUp()
    {
        $mockObj = $this->getMockFromAbstractClass(BaseClass::class);
        $ref = new ReflectionClass($mockObj);
        $ref_prop = $ref->getProperty('arrayField');
        $ref_prop->setAccessible(true);
        $ref_prop->setValue($mockObj, [an_array]);
        $this->sut = $mockObj;
    }

    // .. some test methods that tests methods of abstract class

    public function testGetModifiedArrayFieldReturnsExpectedArray()
    {
        $expected = [array_i_expect];
        $actual = $this->sut->getModifiedArrayField([constraints_i_provide]);
        
        $this->assertEquals($expected, $actual);
    }
```

Now, I read that it is not a good practice to use Reflection to change the visibility just for the sake of test.

So I've two questions:

1. Does the testing community find this approach just a 'light offense' and not a big crime?
2. Should I design this class differently so that I can get rid of the reflection? If yes, any approaches you'd suggest?

---

## UPDATE:

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44264987/1306046) by [Schleis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/498699/schleis) got me thinking, and after some chats with my friends and some resources on the Internet I chose to tackle this problem by introducing an extra argument to the function I needed to test.

I'll proceed further by trying to generalize the function and move it to an ArrayHelper kind of class which makes 1) Testing it easier and 2) Allows other parts of the code to utilize the method if need be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with using reflection is that you are exposing the classes internals.  Unit tests help in demonstrating that your code works correctly but will also allow you to refactor things and verify that you have not changed any current functionality.

So using reflection to change the visibility of an internal property means that you can remove/change that property later.  For example, you may find that you can just calculate it on the fly or something similar.

Difficultly in testing a class is a code smell.

Why is `$arrayField` only set via an abstract method?  What happens if I don't call that method in an implementation of this class before calling `getModifiedArrayField()`?

It is difficult to tell what you are intending with this class and the methods based on the names and description in your post.  However, I think that you may need to consider more what it is that you want your class to be doing.  And change your classes to require having an `$arrayField` provided upon constructor or provide a simple public method to set the value in this class.

Comment: Thanks for  your answer. Regarding your questions: The abstract method is like a hydrator, which fills in the values of `arrayField` from a Data Provider. And the method I'd like to test just transforms the data to a different format so that the preexisting codebase can do its thing to the returned data. I guess a better idea would be to move the transformation to a separate class and run that on whatever this class returns, or just pass an additional argument to the function, although I'm not quite sure about the performance overheads to that.